# Export table to Datatable "Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined"

Tags: jquery

Hello Everyone I want to export the table through Jquery datable. And i am going to make this table in mvc foreach loop. after that i am using jquery datatable for export my datatable but it's giving an error `"Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined"` on this code.

```
<tr style="width:100%; background-color:#d08702">
    <td style="font-weight:600;color:white;text-align:center">Verified Data</td>
</tr>
```

below i have share the full code. please help me to fix this issue.

here is the complete code related to that table

HTML Table

```
<div id="gridContent2" class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table-bordered w-100" id="tableValidationReport">
        <thead>
            <tr class="webgrid-header">
                <th scope="col" colspan="2">
                </th>
                <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 1</th>
                <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="webgrid-header-inner">
                <th scope="col">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Code
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Total
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Total1
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    SalesTotal
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                var ClearData = ViewBag.ClearData as List<TestDTO>;
                var NonClearData = ViewBag.NonClearData as List<TestDTO>;
                var dataAvailable = false;
            }
            @{var index = 0;}



            @if (ClearData != null && ClearData.Count > 0)
            {
                dataAvailable = dataAvailable || true;
                <tr style="width:100%; background-color:#d08702">
                    <td style="font-weight:600;color:white;text-align:center">Verified Data</td>
                </tr>
                foreach (var item in ClearData)
                {
                    <tr class="@(index % 2 == 0 ? "webgrid-row-style" : "webgrid-alternating-row")" style="@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name) ? "background-color:#CCCCCC" : "")">
                        <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAgentsCount">@item.Name</label> </span> </td>
                        <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAgentsCount">@item.Code</label> </span> </td>
                        <td class="col2Width"> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAppointmentTotal">@item.Total</label> </span>  </td>
                        <td class="col2Width"> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblPresentationTotal">@item.Total1</label> </span>  </td>
                        <td class="col2Width"> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblSalesTotal">@item.SalesTotal</label> </span>  </td>
                    </tr>
                    index++;
                }
            }


            @if (NonClearData != null && NonClearData.Count > 0)
            {
                dataAvailable = dataAvailable || true;
                {
                    <tr style="width:100%; background-color:#d08702">
                        <td style="font-weight:600;color:white;text-align:center">Non Verified Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    foreach (var item in NonClearData)
                    {
                        <tr class="@(index % 2 == 0 ? "webgrid-row-style" : "webgrid-alternating-row")" style="@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name) ? "background-color:#CCCCCC" : "")">
                            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAgentsCount">@item.Name</label> </span> </td>
                            <td class="col2Width">  <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAgentsCount">@item.Code</label> </span> </td>
                            <td class="col2Width"> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAppointmentTotal">@item.Total</label> </span>  </td>
                            <td class="col2Width"> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblPresentationTotal">@item.Total1</label> </span>  </td>
                            <td class="col2Width"> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblSalesTotal">@item.SalesTotal</label> </span>  </td>
                        </tr>
                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }


            @if (!dataAvailable)
            {
                <tr><td colspan="21">No Data Found</td></tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

javscript code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;

        var table = $('#tableValidationReport').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
              {
                  extend: 'collection',
                  text: 'Export',
                  buttons: ['pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5']
              }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this DataTables forum post => https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32575/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined#Comment_100647

`colspan` is fine to use in the `thead` cells, but you cannot use it in the `tbody`. Each row of your `tbody` must have the same number of table cells as specified by the total span of columns in your header. Here is what you would have to do in your "Verified" and "Not Verified" rows to have the plugin function properly:

```
    <tr style="width:100%; background-color:#d08702">
        <td style="font-weight:600;color:white;text-align:center">Verified Data</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

the sum of colspan is 2+2+2=6 and $(".webgrid-header-inner>th").length == 5